# What would happen if I plugged a power adapter into two different sockets

Tags: power-supply, mains

So I just purchased a multi way power strip from Costco US (by Cyberpower). The placement of the sockets are in such a way that every socket is the exact distance of each hole so that if you put a plug in it you could get it in the socket or accidentally end up straddling the socket beside it.

What would happen if you plugged a device and accidentally straddled two socket?

Comment: Wow, I never thought someone already had the exact same question.  I wonder if this is intentional!  This interesting placement allowed me to plug in a two prong plug between two very fat plugs :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably nothing bad.

You’ll be plugging into hot & neutral either way, so your equipment will power normally.

A caveat: it's possible that you could inadvertently bypass a fuse, or suppressor, depending on how the power strip is built (ex: if your power strip protects neutral in one row, and line/hot in the adjacent row). In this case, it could be possible that the plug would not use the fuse in either row. Although this would be a terrible design, and not likely.

Comment: Not so. If the sockets are all configured the same then looking across the power pins (with the Earth pin on top or bottom) they would be A-N,A-N,A-N  or N-A,N-A,N-A etc. If you plug a 2 pin plug into two adjacent sockets all you do is swap A and N. This should make no difference to a plugpack. This would only be possible of course if the A-N pins are the non-polarized variety. For example it would be difficult with American plugs since one pin is wider that the other.

Comment: I don’t see how that conflicts with what I wrote. You described my “first case” scenario. The other cases would be true if the second row of sockets are upside down wrt the first row - which would be weird, but possible.

Comment: @JackCreasey I only include the caveat to cover the rare case where a power strip may protect neutral in one row, and line in the adjacent row. In this case, it could be possible that the plug would not use the fuse in either row.  This would be a terrible design, but possible.

Comment: @JackCreasey Also, it’s worth pointing out that some power strips allow you to rotate the sockets independently. I have some of these. They’re great when you need to distribute 90 degree plugs (for example https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00EZ6L2TI/). In this case having one row upside down from the other wouldn’t be too odd.

Comment: The rotating plug A-N are not in line unless they are all turned round .....and of course the only scenario that woks out in your answer is the first one ....the others are not possible.

Comment: @JackCreasey That’s true of course for the link I sent; it was just an example of rotating sockets. And you’re almost  certainly correct that there isn’t a power strip sold which has the rows misaligned, or where one row has ground at the top and the other at the bottom. But then again, I haven’t come across a strip where it’s possible to plug into two sockets with a single cord. At any rate, I think the answer is clear, and it covers all contingencies. I do agree with you though.

Comment: @JackCreasey Me: "I haven’t come across a strip where it’s possible to plug into two sockets with a single cord"... actually, with a Google search I was able to find plenty which look like this could happen. Since the upside down case is so improbable (and I completely agree with you on this), I'm going to edit that out. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, where the outlet strip has a single plug and cord, here are the options that could occur.

1. Three wire grounded plug:  it won't plug in since there is no entry to accept the ground pin.
2. Polarized 2-wire plug: In spite of the socket to socket spacing, the larger neutral prong on the plug will have to align with the larger entry on the socket, so no consequence.
3. Non-polarized plug:  It's possible that the neutral prong could enter the Line socket entry, but this could happen without straddling sockets.

Conclusion:  No electrical difference straddling two sockets.